# What trouble could bring assigning reversed() to a swift array?

Tags: arrays, swift, types

I'm wondering about the reversed() method on a swift Array:

```
var items = ["a", "b", "c"]

items = items.reversed()
```

the signature of the reversed method from the Apple doc says that it returns a

`ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<Element>>`

could that be assigned back to items without doing what the apple doc say which is

> For example, to get the reversed version of an array, initialize a new Array instance from the result of this reversed() method.

or would it give problem in the future? (since the compiler doesn't complain)

Comment: You should follow the docs. Because in the future releases they might change something that might affect `this`

Comment: It's mostly an optimization for execution time and memory, because it does not require creating a helper array and replacing each element

Comment: I am 100% sure that you'll not encounter errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 overloads of reversed() for an Array in Swift 3:

1. Treating the Array as a RandomAccessCollection,
   [`func reversed() -> ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Self>`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/randomaccesscollection/1786190-reversed) (O(1))
2. Treating the Array as a BidirectionalCollection,
   [`func reversed() -> ReversedCollection<Self>`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bidirectionalcollection/1782128-reversed) (O(1))
3. Treating the Array as a Sequence,
   [`func reversed() -> [Self.Iterator.Element]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641355-reversed) (O(n))

[image: Protocols conformed by Array]

By default, `reversed()` pick the RandomAccessCollection's overload and return a ReversedRandomAccessCollection. However, when you write

```
items = items.reversed()
```

you are forcing the RHS to return a type convertible to the LHS (`[String]`). Thus, only the 3rd overload that returns an array will be chosen.

That overload will copy the whole sequence (thus O(n)), so there is no problem overwriting the original array.

---

Instead of `items = items.reversed()`, which creates a copy of the array, reverse that and copy it back, you could reach the same effect using the mutating function [`items.reverse()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection/2802096-reverse), which does the reversion in-place without copying the array twice.

Comment: Good Explanation. Allow me to make your last note more clear for viewers that they are not familiar with "mutating", by mentioning that `reversed()` returns a new separated copy of the array which will be reserved, but `reserve()` will affect (reserve) the array itself, without returning a new copy.

Comment: @AhmadF. Thanks. Inserted some explanation into the answer.

Comment: That's even better! Thank you for your time and consideration :)

Comment: @ahmad s/reserve/reverse/g