# Why result of reversed() does behave itself like being an Array?

Tags: swift

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func prefixSum() -> [Int] {
        var sum = 0
        return map { element in
            defer { sum += element }
            return sum
        }
    }
    
    func suffixSum() -> [Int] {
        reversed().prefixSum().reversed()
    }
}
```

The code above perfectly works.
The question is why does it work?

The function `reversed()` returns not an Array. It returns `ReversedCollection<Array>`. So result of `reversed()` should **not** have function `prefixSum()` defined. And returning type also should mismatch: function `suffixSum()` expects an Array to be returned.
I thought `suffixSum()` should be written like this (which, of course, also works):

```
func suffixSum() -> [Int] {
    Array(Array(reversed()).prefixSum().reversed())
}
```

Comment: There are several overloads of `reversed()` and one of them returns an array. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42688679/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53321158/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Generic implementation `extension Collection where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {` `var prefixSum: [Element] { indices.map { self[..<$0].reduce(.zero,+) } }` `var suffixSum: [Element] { indices.map { self[$0...].dropFirst().reduce(.zero,+) } }` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: That are O(n^2) implementations because every sum is calculated separately instead of O(n) where the each element is added to the previously calculated sum.