# Cannot convert value of type 'ReversedCollection<String>' to expected argument type '[String.Element]' (aka 'Array<Character>')

Tags: swift

```
func test(input: String) -> Bool {
    let reversed = input.reversed()
    let inputArray = Array(input)
    
    return reversed == inputArray 
}
```

I am getting the error `Cannot convert value of type 'ReversedCollection<String>' to expected argument type '[String.Element]' (aka 'Array<Character>')` from compiler with above function

BUT same function without properties as below, directly comparing works perfectly, Can someone explain me with details please ?

```
func test(input: String) -> Bool {
   return input.reversed() == Array(input)    
}
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/53321158/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42688679/1187415

Comment: @MartinR thank you very much. Should i delete my question or better to keep it here ?

Comment: That is up to you. If the other Q&A answers your question then we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @ayfer check your email I have sent you the final project

Comment: @LeoDabus i checked and sent a new one, please check